# How to output a PHP array within a particular column of an html table

Tags: php, html-table

I want the product(s) column to list down all the products inside it's column, same with the Quantity column, it should print out the quantity against each product in the product(s) column. Closest I've gotten is shown in the picture at the bottom.

```
    $cartOutput = "";
    // Dynamic table row assembly.
    $cartOutput .= '<tr>';
    $cartOutput .= '<td>' .$order_id. '</td>';
    $cartOutput .= '<td>'."Pending.". '</td>';
    $cartOutput .= '<td>'.$payment_type. '</td>';

    foreach($result_array as $listitem) 
                    { 
                    $cartOutput .= '<td>'.$listitem. '</td>';
                    $cartOutput .= '<tr>'.'</tr>';

                    //echo '</tr>';
                    } 
                    $i=0;

    foreach($quantity_array as $listitem) 
                    { 
                    $cartOutput .= '<td>'.$listitem. '</td>';
                    $cartOutput .= '<tr>'.'</tr>';
                    //echo '<td></td>';
                    //echo '</tr>';
                    } 
    $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
```

[image: http://i58.tinypic.com/15p0i1y.png]

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the items in a single cell, then why are you surrounding each item with `<td>` and `</td>`? This would be more appropriate:

```
echo '<td>';
foreach(...) {
   echo $listitem . '<br />';
}
echo '</td>'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make them come under one single cell?..I want the names of the products to be displayed in a vertical manner under the column products

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cartOutput = "";
$cartOutput .= '<tr>';
$cartOutput .= '<td>' .$order_id. '</td>';
$cartOutput .= '<td>'."Pending.". '</td>';
$cartOutput .= '<td>'.$payment_type. '</td>';
$cartOutput .= '<td>';
foreach($result_array as $listitem) { 
    echo $listitem.PHP_EOL;
} 
$cartOutput .= '</td>';
$cartOutput .= '<td>';
foreach($quantity_array as $itemquntity) { 
    echo $itemquntity.PHP_EOL;
} 
$cartOutput .= '</td>';
$cartOutput .= '</tr>';
?>
```